# SUM on spss with loop

Tags: statistics, spss

I'm trying to write a syntax code in order to perform a sum of values of different cases of the same variable. I need a loop the changes the selection of the cases for each sum based on two different variables (from the one I'm performing the sum with). It would be so nice to save the various results as a new variable but that's optional.

to give you an idea:

```
id.     1.     2.   1.  2.      
var1.   23.    34.  23.  34      
var2.   46.    37.  45.  56 


sum1 (id=1 & var1=23) = 46 + 45; 
sum2 (id=2 & var1=34) = 37 + 56
```

I already tried something like

```
LOOP #i=1 to 7.
LOOP #j=1 to 10.
COMPUTE filter_$=(var1 = #j  &  id = #i). 
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ 'var1 = #j  &  id = #i (FILTER)'. 
VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'. 
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0). 
FILTER BY filter_$. 
DESCRIPTIVES VARIABLES=var2 
 /STATISTICS=SUM.
END LOOP.
END LOOP.
```

I really need help since I'm not a developer and having a lot of trouble working this out.

Answer (score 1):

No need for looping or iterating :) - SPSS `aggregate` command can perform this kind of task easily:

```
aggregate out=* mode=add /break=id var1 /yourSum=sum(var2).
```

BTW this will add the sums as a new variable in the dataset, as you wanted.

Comment: Glad to help! Please click on the check mark beside the answer to accept it as the solution.